# An array function that returns an array containing all elements appearing a certain number of times

Tags: javascript, array

```
Array.prototype.itemsWithQuantity = function(n) {
    var counts = {};
    var result = [];
    var i = this.length;
    while(i--){
        counts[this[i]] = counts[this[i]] == undefined ? 1 : counts[this[i]] + 1;       
    }
    i = this.length;
    var alreadyPushed = {};
    while(i--){
        if(counts[this[i]] == n && !alreadyPushed[this[i]]){
            alreadyPushed[this[i]] = true;
            result.push(this[i]);
        }       
    }
    return result;
};
```

Above is my function that returns all the items in an array with a certain quantity. E.g., `[1,2,3,2,3,4].itemsWithQuantity(2) == [2,3]`.

Not only is the code kinda ugly, but I also have a feeling there's a more efficient way to do it that I'm not spotting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could use [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to do the counting and later[`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the elements with the desired number of occurences.

It reduces the bookkeeping to the minimum of `counts`, goodbye `alreadyPushed`. It also reduces the boilerplateness a little, by giving you local variables implicitely:

- You have `this[i]` everywhere, which can look a little cryptic. You could store it in a local `var element = this[i];` which could be considered more readable.
- in my suggested code, you get those local variables as a result of using functions that receive the value as a parameter which you can of course name however you want.

I think it depends on how much you are used to seeing certain patterns show up in code. After doing it for a while, you know that

```
var i = this.length;
while(i--){ //...}
```

will iterate over all the elements. `Array.forEach()` calls it by its name, which can improve readability.

I had my first ever go at the built in scripting thingy here on stackexchange, take a look and try the code:

```js
Array.prototype.itemsWithQuantity = function(n) {
  var counts = {};

  // count
  this.forEach(function(element) {
    counts[element] = counts[element] == undefined ? 1 : counts[element] + 1
  });

  // return those elements (which are the keys(=property names) of the object) occuring n times
  return Object.keys(counts).filter(function(element) {
    return counts[element] == n;
  });
};

var input = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5];
var output = input.itemsWithQuantity(2);

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output.toString();
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Instead of `forEach`, you could use `reduce`.

Comment: @I'll add comments tomorrow Concerning "... counts[element] == undefined ? ..." : My first thought was to use JavaScript's in-operator: "elements in counts[element]". Strangely nobody took that approach. So I ask myself if it would have some disadvantages which I don't know? Or would it work the same?

Comment: @st88 no idea, I sticked to the way I assign the property. I didn't really think about `in` to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

You can (ab-)use the short-circuit logic of Javascript to make the last line a little more readable:

```js
counts[this[i]] = (counts[this[i]] || 0) + 1;
```

Comment: When you use a for-in loop with an array, you iterate over every property of the object, which will include methods attached by extending the prototype.  It would be a problem here if I ever passed in the parameter 1. And it would be poor practice even if I wasn't passing in a parameter of 1, since it would perform extra iterations.

Comment: But your second point is good, thanks :)

Comment: Ugh, you're right. Haven't touched Javascript in a while and forgot that array iterators work on array indices instead of array elements (as they usually do in other languages). They don't iterate over all object properties as you claim though (just tested in Firefox).

Answer (score 1):

I would use Javascripts ability to `reduce` Arrays (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)).

```
function itemByFrequency(arr, freq){
    function countFrequencies(o,n){
      o[n] = o[n] || 0;
      o[n] += 1;
      return o;
    };
    var fr = arr.reduce(countFrequencies, {});
    function filterFrequencies(o,n){
        if (fr[n]==freq) o.push(n);
        return o;
    }
    return Object.keys(fr).reduce(filterFrequencies, []);
}
```

Here is an example [glot.io](https://glot.io/snippets/ee12n8zgug)

Comment: I went through the same thought process. The problem is that it does check for minimum occurances, not exact ones. If you have more than `n`, it's still part of the result. [I forked your code](https://glot.io/snippets/ee10qh2yx9). To fix this, you'd have to remove the element from `result` again in case of `o[n] == freq +1`, which requires searching through `result`. This makes the approach less intuitive (imo) and harder to read, which is too high of a price for me to pay for single-loopness. Maybe it's even premature optimization.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. I changed the code to my first intended version using `reduce` (twice) - Athough the last one could be using filter ;)

Answer (score 0):

One could combine string-methods with array-methods. So that the used loops are reduced.

```js
function getElementsWithCount(arr, requiredCount) {
  var arrAsString = arr.join(', ');
  var ret = [];
  var alreadyChecked = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // If the element is already in one of the two
    //   collector-arrays then continue.
    if ( ret.indexOf(arr[i]) !== -1 || 
         alreadyChecked.indexOf(arr[i]) !== -1 ) {
      continue;
    }

    var regExp =
        new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + arr[i] + '($|,)', 'g');

    // Compare the occurences within the string with 
    // demanded count.
    arrAsString.match(regExp).length === requiredCount ? 
      ret.push(arr[i]) : 
      alreadyChecked.push(arr[i]);
  }

  return ret;
}

var field = [1,2,3,2,3,4];

console.log( getElementsWithCount(field, 2) );
```

The for-loop is necessary because I want to use continue. Which isn't possible with forEach.

Comment: Note that you can use `return;` inside a `forEach` in the same way you are using that `continue;` inside your `for`

Comment: @Pevara Sometimes one doesn't realize the simplest option although it's obvious.  ;)  Thanks a lot.